# html <select> --> no upload from selected statement

Tags: php, html, select

I am working on a form for a newsletter questionairy. There I have some trouble with some selected statements. The statements which can be selected (value="f" and value "m") will not be uploaded onto the mail server. Maybe someone of you has a solution. The FirstNAme, LAstName and EMail are working.

Here is the code:

```
<div style="margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;width:720px">
<form id="nl2go--form"    action="https://app.newsletter.com/de/recipients/index/subscribe/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<table border="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td><select name="n1go-gender" style="font-size:9pt; background:border: 1px solid #181717; padding: 2px; width: 45pt;" onchange="alert(this.form.n1go-gender.options[this.form.n1go-gender.selectedIndex].value)"> 
<option value="f" selected>Woman</option>
<option value="m">Mister</option>
</select>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="nl2go-firstname" id="nl2go--firstname" style="font-size:9pt; color:#181717; background:border: 1px solid #181717; padding: 2px; width: 107pt;" placeholder="FirstName"/>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="nl2go--lastname" id="nlgo-lastname" style="color:#181717; font-size:9pt; width:107pt; background border: 1px solid #181717; padding: 2px;" placeholder="LastName"/></td>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="nl2go-mail" id="nlgo--mail" style="font-size:9pt;  width:272pt; background border: 1px solid #cccccc; padding: 2px;" placeholder="Your E-Mail"></td>
<tr>
<td align="center"><input type="submit" value="Senden" name="nlgo-submit" id="nlgo-submit" class="jfk-button jfk-button-action">
<input type="hidden" name="nl2go--key" id="nl2go--key" value="dfdfdfdf....."></div></td></tr></table></div></ol>
</form
```

cheers
Vrede

Comment: Is the value defined when you dump the POST value?

Comment: Hi CodeGodie, if I understand you correctly... the value is defined by the newsletter-server. The values are "f" and "m" and the method is POST.

Comment: Dear CodeGodie, I tried to convert the following "radio" statement into the above mentioned <select> statement.                                                <input type="radio" name="nl2go--gender" value="m">m&auml;nnlich <input type="radio" name="nl2go--gender" value="f">weiblich                I also have changed the CSS Clauses. I cannot find the issue, why it isn`t working....

Answer (score 0):

Ugly. You have syntax issues on this line:

```
</div></td></tr></table></div></ol>
```

Thus, breaking your code/form.

Also, try using classes for styling opposed to inline styles.